# How do I display pandas dataframe so that its width fits my screen?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I have a pandas dataframe with textual data and I want to display all texts without truncation so I set

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

However, the table now doesn't fit my screen, you can see the scroll bar at the bottom of the image appeared. I want to display a dataframe so that in width it fits my screen (i.e. cells can grow in height but not in width).[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) lets dataframe be wider than the screen and might not truncate the text so much.

Comment: @Oddaspa Yeah, I don't want it to be wider, I want it to be equal or less the width of what jupyter notebook can display and without truncation of text, so I want cells to grow in height, not in width.

Comment: Then I suggest using pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None).

Comment: It does work when I display 10 rows but when I display 300 rows with `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)` it still expands. I will modify the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution I found

```
from IPython.display import display
display(_df.style.set_properties(**{
        'width': '230px',
        'max-width': '230px'
    }))
```

and I wrote a helper function for this

```
# decorator
def pandas_display(func):
    default_1 = pd.options.display.max_rows
    default_2 = pd.options.display.max_colwidth
    def wrapper(_df, exclude_cols=None, properties=None, limit_float=2):
        pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
        pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None
        func(_df, exclude_cols, properties, limit_float)
        pd.options.display.max_rows = default_1
        pd.options.display.max_colwidth = default_2
    return wrapper
    
    
@pandas_display
def display_df(self, exclude_cols, properties, limit_float):
    if exclude_cols is not None:
        if not isinstance(exclude_cols, list):
            exclude_cols = list(exclude_cols)
        cols = [x for x in self.columns.values if x not in set(exclude_cols)]
        self = self[cols]

    if not properties:
        properties = {
            'text-align': 'left',
            'white-space': 'pre-wrap',
            'word-wrap': 'break-word',
            'width': '230px',
            'max-width': '230px',
        }
        
    a = self.style.set_properties(**properties)
    if limit_float is not None:
        a.format(thousands=',', precision=limit_float)
    display(a)
    
d = display_df
pd.DataFrame.d = d
```

which you can call by `df.d()`